# Can I build cocoa foundation on QtCreator on MacOSX

Tags: xcode, cocoa, qt

I have a *.mm file with C++ project on MacOS. Shall I build this *.mm with this C++ project via QtCreator?

---

or
Xcode can build C++ project with Qt framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Xcode can build C++ project with Qt framework?

Yes

Typing the following line in a terminal will
create an Xcode project:

```
qmake -spec macx-xcode project.pro
```

Take a look at [QT forum](http://qt-project.org/search/tag/xcode) for more details.